# print kth smallest number of an array

Tags: java, arrays

The below code shows wrong output:

Here is my code:

```
int[] x = {7, 10, 4, 20, 15};
int n = x.length; 
int k = 4; 
int ctr = 0;              
                            
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (x[i] > x[j]) {
            ctr++;
        }
        if ((ctr + 1) == k){
            ans = x[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Kth` smallest element try the following:

1. Sort the array using `Arrays.sort` or in case you have to do it yourself use an easy sorting algorithm such as [bubble sort](https://www.javatpoint.com/bubble-sort-in-java);
2. Initialize a `count` variable to 1;
3. Go through the array from `i = 0;` until i = `N - 1` and compare the current and the next element, if they are not equal increase the counter by one, otherwise don't increase it;
4. Stop until counter == `Kth` element

Afterwards you can then improve your code to handle the corner cases such as the array does not have `Kth` elements and so on.

With the aforementioned algorithm for the input

`int[] x = {7, 10, 10, 4, 20, 15}`;

to find the 4th smallest.

1. Sorting array 'x' ->  `{4, 7, 10, 10, 15, 20}`
2. Count = 1;
3. Go through the array 4 != 7 Count = 2;
4. 7 != 10 -> Count = 3;
5. 10 == 10 -> Count = 3;
6. 10 != 15 -> Count = 4;
7. Stop, `15` is the 4th smallest element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your algorithm try this, but I agree with others that solution with array.sorted is better

```
int[] x = {7, 10, 4, 20, 15};
int n = x.length; 
int k = 4; 
int ctr = 0; 
int ans = 0             
                            
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ctr = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (x[i] > x[j]) {
            ctr++;
        }
    }

    if ((ctr + 1) == k){
        ans = x[i];
        break;
    }

}
System.out.println(ans);
```

This method is looking for "a number that is greater than other k numbers in the array" and is not "taking the k-th" like you said

For example this approach would fail in a scenario like the following: {4,2,2,2,2,2} and you are asked to take the 3rd

There is no number that is greater that 2 others: 4 is greater than 5 other numbers, 2 is greater than 0 other numbers
So in your proposal ctr variable will never be = 3 and algorithm will fail.